# how to make sure that boost is successfully installed?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, centos

I'm tring to install a linux tool that explicitly claims boost installation is necessary.(http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Development.GetStarted)

I've downloaded the source code of boost1.42(put in /usr/local/boost1.42) to compile it. Though the compile process produces a lot of errors and warnings(Is it normal? the boost official website says that there should not be other errors but for IO errors.), Finally I got the /stage/lib and /boost in the /usr/local/boost1.42 directory. Now I could run examples like:

```
 #include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );

    while (std::cin)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        boost::smatch matches;
        if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
            std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
    }
}

 $ c++ -I /usr/local/boost_1_42_0 example.cpp -o example -L~/usr/local/boost_1_42_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_regex
```

this will actually emit a excutable file "example", with no compile warnings and correct behavior.
But when I want to see its linkage details with:

```
$ldd -v example
```

the result is quite confusing:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb4b9c000)
    libboost_regex.so.1.42.0 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000003f79600000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003f72e00000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003f78e00000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003f72200000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003f72a00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003f71e00000)

    Version information:
    ./example:
            libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
            libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libpthread.so.0
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
            libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
            libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6:
            libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libm.so.6
            ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
            libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_4.2.0) => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
            libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3) => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
            libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib64/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib64/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    /lib64/libm.so.6:
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1:
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib64/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
    /lib64/libc.so.6:
            ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
            ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0:
            ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
            ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
            ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib64/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/libc.so.6
```

It seems that the linker didn't find the libboost_regex.a in /usr/local/boost1.42/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a (see ldd log: libboost_regex.so.1.42.0 => not found).

So which libary does it really wants to load? why "not found" turns out to produce the right excutable file?

And if I want to make sure boost is successfully installed, do I have to export the /usr/local/boost1.42 and /usr/local/boost1.42/stage/lib to anywhere, so that other programs could know its location?

Thanks!
Hongbin

Comment: Some Linux distributions are packaging boost. You could install the relevant packages.

Comment: Is there some reason you've chosen Boost 1.42? That's a couple of years old by now (current release is 1.49).

Comment: @JerryCoffin actuall I tried 1.49, met with the same problem, so I choice a random one..

Comment: Fair enough -- but since that didn't help, I think I'd go back to 1.49.

Answer (score 3):

To install boost in a non-standard location (not specified in ld.so.conf) and use it do:

1. Configure boost with `--prefix` and `--libdir` options:

   ```
   $ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=${PREFIX} --libdir=${PREFIX}/lib64
   ```
2. Build and install boost setting rpath to the same value as `--libdir`, e.g. `${PREFIX}/lib64`:

   ```
   $ ./b2 -d+2 --layout=system variant=release link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared linkflags="-Wl,-rpath,${PREFIX}/lib64"

   $ sudo ./b2 -d+2 --layout=system variant=release link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared linkflags="-Wl,-rpath,${PREFIX}/lib64" install
   ```
3. Compile your application specifying boost include directory:

   ```
   $ g++ -c -I${PREFIX}/include ...
   ```
4. Link you application specifying boost lib location. Also embed rpath in the binaries, so that the application can find boost libraries without having to fiddle with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

   ```
   $ g++ -L${PREFIX}/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,${PREFIX}/lib64 ...
   ```

In the above set PREFIX to boost install location, e.g. `export PREFIX=/usr/local/my_boost`.

Comment: for me this worked: `./b2 hardcode-dll-paths=true dll-path=${PREFIX}/lib64`

Comment: @HiB Nice one, did not know it was possible with their build system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to tell the dynamic linker where the shared objects (`.so` files, not `.a` files) are located.

This can be done by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the right path (and exporting that), or editing `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or some other settings file depending on the distribution).

(Another option is to use `rpath` options while linking the executable, but the environment settings are more flexible for development.)

Comment: Thanks, mat. actually both the .so and .a are in /usr/local/boost1.42/stage/lib. Could you further explain why the example could be complied correctly even if libboost_regex.so.1.42.0 => not found ?

Comment: You told the compiler (and linker) where to find those files (with `-L`). You didn't tell the runtime linker.

Comment: I'd say that `-Wl,-rpath` is the best option. Environment variables are a poor choice since an application wouldn't be able to start if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set.

Comment: `rpath` is not a good choice if you want to distribute the exe - it would be dependent on having the boost libraries in that strange path. Much better to have the dynamic runtime linker locate the files than hardcoding the dev boxe's paths. (Unless you ship the libraries too.)

Comment: If one distributes executables and uses custom libraries they have to be distributed as well.

Comment: OP isn't installing a "custom" library, he's not modifying boost.

Comment: By _custom_ I mean a library not provided by distribution. Anyway, embedding `rpath` doesn't prevent `ld.so` from looking for a library in the standard locations. There is no good reason not to use it (just make sure the path is not on NFS).